# How to get a 1m precision coordinates?

Tags: position, indoor

I'm working on a project which examines different approaches for indoor positioning. All of these approaches return coordinates (lat/lon). What I need to do is create a digital map to compare returned coordinates to real ones, so I can calculate the error/precision of certain methods. How can I do this?

I was thinking, that I could step in the corners of my room and get precise coordinates and use them as comparison, but obviously it is not as easy as it seems. I have seen a lot of bachelor thesis on this topic, but no-one really shows the implementation of digital map. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What you probably need to do is get a (land) surveyor to calculate the 'known' points for you. If you can't get one to volunteer the time and materials, it could be expensive.

Comment: @mkennedy Is there any other ways of getting "ground truth" of map measurements?

Comment: For that type of precision you either need; a high quality GPS unit that you can differently correct to establish control points or coordinates resulting from a land survey. Many GPS units are able to achieve sub-meter accuracy so, if you collect several measurements through out the day the precision should be a stable location with a degree of quantified error (thus the differential correction). I would highly recommend not using lat/long but rather using a projection that has some local control such as State Plane.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans will GPS work indoors for high accuracy? "The signals from the satellites are attenuated and scattered by roofs, walls and other objects". I have seen it work, but accurate?

Comment: @Mapperz, sorry I ment to indicate that the coordinate collection would occur outdoors to establish control locations.

Comment: Maybe you could check if an Android phone could give you more accurate solution, relying on WiFi hot spots...